# Silent Charniak Parse when it can not parse sentence - It does not work

Tags: c++, parsing, charniak-parser

I am using [charniak parser - bllip-parser](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/tree/master/first-stage) for chunking output. Sometimes parser can not parse sentence. As [README](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/blob/master/first-stage/README), there is one argument '-S' which tells parser to remain silent when it can not parse any sentence and it just goes to next sentence. But using this argument, parser does not go to next sentence. It still throws exception.

My input to parser is :

```
./parseIt, -l400, -K, -t4, -S, -EInputTagFile.txt, ../DATA/EN/, InputTextFile.txt
```

Output of this command (error) :

```
Warning [parseIt.C:266] Sentence 4: Parse failed from 0, inf or nan probabililty -- reparsing without POS constraints
Warning [ChartBase.C:172] Sentence 4: estimating the counts on a zero-probability sentence
parseIt: MeChart.C:105: Bst& MeChart::findMapParse(): Assertion `s' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong with '-S' argument ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings were due to a bug and should be fixed now. See the [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/issues/17).

The parser shouldn't be run in multithreaded mode (it's not really threadsafe) which I suspect is the source of the assertion failure and subsequent `abort()`.

Comment: After applying patch and removing argument - `-l400` - It works perfectly. Sentence was near about 400 characters long. That's why I have used `-l400`. But If I use `-l400` or more than 400, It will throw same exception. I think threads doesn't matter here in my case.
I have changed max sentence length to 999 in 'Feature.h'.
Thank you David.